# String to HashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

The String looks like:

```
{"toGroup":"aaa@gmail.com, bbb@gmail.com", "ccGroup":"ccc@gmail.com, ddd@gmail.com"}
```

Since there are commas inside the values, I can't simply split it by comma. So how can I make a HashMap from this String?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a valid JSON object. Use some JSON parsing library to parse it into a data structure of your liking. A few possibilities:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html
  https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

For your given input, this will work:

```
String input = "{\"toGroup\":\"aaa@gmail.com, bbb@gmail.com\", \"ccGroup\":\"ccc@gmail.com, ddd@gmail.com\"}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\":\"([^\"]+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    map.put(key, value);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

If you have other input where this approach would break,
perhaps you can tweak this to the desired effect.